# Полоска между фотографиями в html, css

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

[image: полоска между тегами]

*html*:

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vinloud - разработка сайтов</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="site">
        <div class="logo">
          <h3>Vinloud - разработка сайтов</h3>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="about">
          <p>About us...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <a class="link" href="index.html", target="_blank">
            <img src="icons/vk.png" />
          </a>
          <a class="link" href="index.html", target="_blank">
            <img src="icons/telegram.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*css*:

````
    background-color: beige;
}


.logo{
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(32, 32, 34)
}
  
.about{
    color: rgb(44, 44, 46);
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;    
}

.links {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.link:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.links img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.links img:hover {
    background: rgb(240,240, 202);
    border-radius: 50%;
}```
````

Comment: `.links a.link { text-decoration:none;}` или что-то типа того

Answer (score 1):

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/47c22db0ac53de7cd4af541266900de2?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
</a>
```